# "Class is Already defined" error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have listview app exploring cities each row point to diffrent city , in each city activity include button when clicked open new activity which is infinite gallery contains pics of that city , i add infinite gallery to first city and work fine , when i want to add it to the second city , it gave me red mark error in the class as follow :

1- The type InfiniteGalleryAdapter is already defined.

2-The type InfiniteGallery is already defined.

I tried to change class name with the same result, I delete R.java and eclipse rebuild it with same result. Also I unchecked the java builder from project properties and get same red mark error.

Please any help and advice will be appreciated

thanks

My Code:

```
public class SecondCity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Boolean customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE); 
        // Set the layout to use
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        if (customTitleSupported) {
            getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.custom_title); 
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv); 
            Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"BFantezy.ttf");     
            tv.setTypeface(face);
            tv.setText("MY PICTURES"); 
        }

        InfiniteGallery galleryOne = (InfiniteGallery) findViewById(R.id.galleryOne);
        galleryOne.setAdapter(new InfiniteGalleryAdapter(this));     
    }
}


class InfiniteGalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 
    **//red mark here (InfiniteGalleryAdapter)** 
    private Context mContext;

    public InfiniteGalleryAdapter(Context c, int[] imageIds) { 
        this.mContext = c;
    } 

    public int getCount() { 
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    } 

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    } 

    public long getItemId(int position) { 
        return position;
    } 

    private LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public InfiniteGalleryAdapter(Context a) { 
        this.mContext = a; 
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService ( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)
    } 

    public class ViewHolder{ 
        public TextView text; 
        public ImageView image;
    } 

    private int[] images = {
        R.drawable.pic_1, R.drawable.pic_2, 
        R.drawable.pic_3, R.drawable.pic_4, 
        R.drawable.pic_5
    }; 

    private String[] name = {
        "This is first picture (1) " ,
        "This is second picture (2)",
        "This is third picture (3)", 
        "This is fourth picture (4)",
        " This is fifth picture (5)"
    }; 

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
        ImageView i = getImageView(); 

        int itemPos = (position % images.length); 

        try {
            i.setImageResource(images[itemPos]); ((BitmapDrawable) i.getDrawable()).
            setAntiAlias  (true);
        } 

        catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            Log.e("InfiniteGalleryAdapter", "Out of memory creating imageview. Using empty view.", e);
        } 

        View vi=convertView; 
        ViewHolder holder; 
        if(convertView==null){ 
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_items, null); 
            holder=new ViewHolder(); holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
            holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image); 
            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
        } 
        holder.text.setText(name[itemPos]); 

        final int stub_id=images[itemPos]; 
        holder.image.setImageResource(stub_id); 

        return vi;
    } 

    private ImageView getImageView() { 

        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext); 

        return i;
    } 
}

class InfiniteGallery extends Gallery {
    **//red mark here (InfiniteGallery)** 

    public InfiniteGallery(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    } 

    public InfiniteGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public InfiniteGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        // These are just to make it look pretty
        setSpacing(25);
        setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
    } 

    public void setResourceImages(int[] name){
        setAdapter(new InfiniteGalleryAdapter(getContext(), name));
        setSelection((getCount() / 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you break up the code blocks into different classes? Kind of hard to see where classes start and end right now.

Comment: That's a bit much to go through.  Do you think that you could narrow down the specific portion that's got the error?

Comment: @Makoto i post the whole class which the project contain only one class for the infinite gallery and is resulted from merge the original 4 class also i wrote in above code where i get error , thanks

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project? Browse through your src/bin folders to see if there are some leftover files from before the merge.

Comment: @Torious yes i clean it and browse it nothing left there, still the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting those red marks as these class are already defined in one of your previous class. Java won't let have duplicate names. Also it seems you are trying to define same classes for every Actvitiy which is redundant.

Just remove the two classes completely from your SecondActivity java file as they are already defined in a previous activity. I would suggest you to make a separate package where the Adapter and InfiniteGallery are defined and kept to be reused .

```
public class SecondCity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Boolean customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE); 
        // Set the layout to use
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        if (customTitleSupported) {
            getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.custom_title); 
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv); 
            Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"BFantezy.ttf");     
            tv.setTypeface(face);
            tv.setText("MY PICTURES"); 
        }

        InfiniteGallery galleryOne = (InfiniteGallery) findViewById(R.id.galleryOne);
        galleryOne.setAdapter(new InfiniteGalleryAdapter(this));     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have even defined the class with the same name on some other file in the same folder. Which can cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ctrl+H -> Java Search -> Search for Type
It will tell you where the duplicated class is.